# Cross origin issue with polymer cdn

Tags: polymer, cross-domain, cdn

I am trying to use the polymer cdn: https://polygit.org/

I am getting the following error:

> Redirect at origin 'http://polygit.org' has been blocked from loading
>   by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my html head imports:

```
<base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
```

Comment: Is that all you're doing? Polygit works fine for me on localhost

Comment: i have the same issue with external cdn, i wish i knew the answer!

Comment: You need to add more information; there shouldn't be a problem with those two tags. Are you using the [HTML5 doc type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5)? What browser are you using?